How to add custom field content to Gutenberg editor?
I have created an ACF fields assigned to all post types. It is a Flexible layout 'bhld-codes' with a textarea field 'bhld-code-css' and radio buttons 'bhld-codes-where'. What I want to achieve is to place the content from the 'bhld-code-css' field directly in the admin panel, in the Gutenberg editor, but NOT in the content of the page. The goal is to make the CSS code added in the 'bhld-code-css' field work throughout the editor, not just on the page content.
My code:
function test_function() {
        if (is_admin() && is_single() || is_page() ) {

            if (have_rows('bhld-codes')) {
                while (have_rows('bhld-codes')) {
                    the_row();
    
                    $bhld_side = sanitize_text_field(get_sub_field('bhld-codes-where')); // radio buttons options
    
                    if (get_row_layout() == 'bhld-code-css') {
                        $css_code = sanitize_text_field(get_sub_field('bhld-code-css')); // textarea with code
    
                        $load_function = function () use ($css_code) {
                            echo '<style>' . $css_code . '</style>';
                        };
    
                        if (($bhld_side == 'back') || ($bhld_side == 'both')) {
                            add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', $load_function);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // rest of the code
                    }
    
                }
            }

       }
    }
    add_action('init', 'test_function');

What Am I doing wrong?
